# Azure function - can not read variable.json file

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have some variables which are going to be used by the business logic part of a function. Therefore, instead of adding them inside the appsetting.json file, I have added a separated file as variable.json
Testing on my machine works but after deploy, it seems function can not find it. and I got an error:
[image]

The properties for this file is like the below image. (The build action was None before, but nothing has been changed even by content)

[image]

and the below image shows how it looks like in root
[image]

And because of that reason, any call the response will be "*Function host is not running.*"

The code for reading this file (path = "Variables.json")

```
 private static List<Variable> GetVariables(string path)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
        var variables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Variable>>(json);

        return variables;
    }
```

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show the code of how to use the variables.json?

Comment: @BowmanZhu I have updated the post with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was because when we start Azure Function locally the file `varibale.json` is available by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but published on azure portal it's `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\site\wwwroot"`

To get the correct folder path you can use following code:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "varibale.json");
    // ...
}
```

For startup.cs, you can use the following code:

```
var executioncontextoptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
var currentDirectory = executioncontextoptions.AppDirectory;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! is it any way to get this on startup?
this context is available through  func runtime and not startup time